# SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: json, angular, angular-services

I want to get string value by calling API into Angular.
Here is what I am doing
Service file -

```
 public getRespondDashboardUrl(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`ref/RespondDashboardUrl`);
  }
```

component file

```
respondDashboardLink: string;
this.refService.getRespondDashboardUrl().subscribe(result => {
  this.respondDashboardLink = result;
});
```

funcation returns URL as string value https://abcd.xyz.com/Respond/App/index.html#ActionCenter/0

error I am getting

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4000/vendor.js:33488:51)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4000/polyfills.js:8108:31)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4000/vendor.js:78969:33)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4000/polyfills.js:8107:60)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4000/polyfills.js:7880:47)
>       at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4000/polyfills.js:8183:34)
>       at invokeTask (http://localhost:4000/polyfills.js:9429:14)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4000/polyfills.js:9466:21)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you response type is string. more type check [responseType](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#responseType).

```
this.http.get(`ref/RespondDashboardUrl`, {responseType: 'text'})
```

Comment: grr you beat me to it :)

Comment: Simple solution, but great!!